# Can't load Crystal reportin VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How to fix it, my VB cant load my crystal report
this is error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Keuangan.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

and this my code :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        Else
            ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0
            ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0
            Dim ReportKu As ReportDocument
            'menentukan lokasi report yang akan ditampilkan
            ReportKu.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\Keuangan\Keuangan\Lap_Harian.rpt")
            'nilai parameter TanggalMulai di ambil dari inputan dtpTanggalMulai
            ReportKu.SetParameterValue("Harinya", ComboBox1.Text)
            'nilai parameter TanggalSelesai di ambil dari inputan dtpTanggalSelesai
            'tampilkan ke CrystalReportViewer1
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ReportKu
            CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()


        End If
    End Sub
```

My Full code

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Public Class Laporan
    Dim dr As OdbcDataReader
    Dim conn As OdbcConnection
    Dim cmd As OdbcCommand
    Sub koneksinya()
        conn = New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Dsn=db_pkluptd")
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        Else
            ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0
            ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0
            Dim ReportKu As ReportDocument
            'menentukan lokasi report yang akan ditampilkan
            ReportKu.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\Keuangan\Keuangan\Lap_Harian.rpt")
            'nilai parameter TanggalMulai di ambil dari inputan dtpTanggalMulai
            ReportKu.SetParameterValue("Harinya", ComboBox1.Text)
            'nilai parameter TanggalSelesai di ambil dari inputan dtpTanggalSelesai
            'tampilkan ke CrystalReportViewer1
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ReportKu
            CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()


        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Laporan_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call koneksinya()
        cmd = New OdbcCommand("select distinct Tanggal as tgl from tbl_transaksi", conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Pilih")
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        While dr.Read()
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(dr.Item("tgl"))
        End While
        cmd = New OdbcCommand("select distinct month(Tanggal) as bulan from tbl_transaksi", conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("Pilih")
        ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0
        While dr.Read()

            ComboBox2.Items.Add(dr.Item("bulan"))
        End While

        cmd = New OdbcCommand("select distinct year(Tanggal) as tahun from tbl_transaksi", conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        ComboBox3.Items.Add("Pilih")
        ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0
        While dr.Read()
            ComboBox3.Items.Add(dr.Item("tahun"))
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug the code, a null reference exception is usually easy to spot.

Well, how to debug? =
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

try to use New keyword

```
 Dim ReportKu As New ReportDocument
```